# 'gcloud' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: windows, google-app-engine

I have installed google cloud sdk for window 7. (Not Using Cygwin)after running the setup, I closed and reopened the cmd.exe and entered inside the google-cloud-sdk directory. when I run the command-- gcloud auth login getting error

'gcloud' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

any help appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the path of the folder containing 'gcloud' into PATH variable

Comment: I have already added the path variable